# How to get Notification payload in WatchOS2?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, watchos-2

I have implemented Dynamic and Static notification in current Watch App. Even I am able to receive event in `- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification` method in case of any action in Dynamic Notification.

- Now my concern is, how to receive any event/callback on tapping Notification view that actually opens the WatchOS App ?
- How can I get the Push Notification Payload in any method on launching app by tapping notification ?

I am using the following method to set UI in case of Dynamic Notification interface. but, this will not be the case for Static one.

```
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler { 
    NSLog(@"%@",remoteNotification);
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
}
```

**EDIT**

I have added following code in appdelegate to register for Notifications.

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the following delegate method, with regard to your Watch App's extension delegate, for the answer to both of your questions:

```
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification
```

*Perimeters:*

- Identifier: equals "" (empty `NSString`) if the app is launched without tapping one of the notification buttons, or equal to the identifier you set to the notification action button if the user launches the app by tapping one of the notification's action buttons.
- remoteNotification: the payload that came with the remote notification. It is in the format of a Dictionary, and so you can get the payload from this object.

**Answer to Question 1:**
When the user launches the app, if implemented, this method will be called and allow you to reconfigure the app based on the user's selection.

**Answer to Question 2:**
The payload has the traditional structure of the Apple Notification Payload dictionary. The `aps` key contains the `alert` information and the `badge` information. Then your custom data is attached to the overall dictionary. To access it, if you configure the payload dictionary with a key "testKey", you could access it by using `remoteNotification[@"testKey"]`.

**Update**

According to Apple, the static notification "must not include controls, tables, maps, or other interactive elements," because it is only to be used as a fallback if the interactive notification cannot be launched in a timely manner. Source: [Apple watchOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html).

Sources and/or Additional Resources:

[Apple Developer: WK InterfaceController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:)

[Apple Developer: The Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

[Apple Developer: Notification Essentials for watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

Comment: In My case This method is not getting call on tapping on Notification.

Comment: @Mrug Have you registered the User Notification Settings by calling UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings), as specified in this document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1?

Comment: I have added code in appdelegate to register. have also posted it as Edit in Question.

Comment: I just updated the answer. According to Apple's watchOS Developer Library, the static notification UI should not have any interactive buttons, that is why it is not firing any methods. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I have not used Static Notification only, this is the case in both dynamic as well as static. none of them are providing any callback dear.

Comment: Actually I have tried to implement handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification in WatchDelegate as well as in Launch Interface as well as in NotificationController too but none of place is getting call back on taping dynamic notification.

Comment: From what I have read, `handleActionWithIdentifier` should go in the WatchKitExtension Delegate. Are you testing on an actual device or the simulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110793/discussion-between-mrug-and-jake-chasan).